# Remove and replace all Slashes from Filenames recursively

Tags: find, rename, regex

I want to rename every File in a folder-subsystem that contains a slash to be replaced with an underscore

Current filenames example:

```
Hello/there.txt
File/name.jpg
```

to

```
Hello_there.txt
File_name.jpg
```

The files are in different subfolders of the same folder-system and the slashes are in different positions.
I have tried to use the rename-command as follows:

```
rename "s/\//_/g" *
```

But I could not get any success. Could you give me a lead in the right direction?

Comment: `Hello/there.txt` in GNU/Linux normally means file there.txt in directory Hello. Do you want to move the files or rename them?

Comment: @Bruni Yes, I'm well aware of that, but the files I'm targetting are actually from a usb-stick created on a windows-system and need to be renamed and have all slashes on the usb-stick removed.

Comment: Maybe this https://superuser.com/questions/510337/cant-rename-a-file-the-name-of-which-starts-with-a-hyphen helps you.

Comment: Each slash represents a boundary between a directory and a sub-directory or the file name itself. So to replace a the slash with an underscore implies that you also **move** the file from a sub-directory to the current directory. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Yes, I created a usb-stick for testing the entire process. I created the 2 files Hello/there.txt
File/name.jpg
and want to rename them to:
Hello_there.txt
File_name.jpg

Comment: Do you see the slashes when running Ubuntu or running Windows?

Comment: I see the slashes in both systems

Comment: What is shown by the command `find -ls`, when run in Ubuntu (in the top directory of the USB stick)? "find space minus ell ess"

Comment: Maybe there is confusion because the slashes were created in Windows, and slashes are not valid in file names in Linux because it denotes the boundary between directories (which corresponds to backslash in Windows). Maybe it works better to remove the slashes in Windows.

Comment: 385      8 drwxr-xr-x   2 user      user          8192 May 14 09:24 ./Main/_Ein\342\201\204Slash

_______________
      390      8 -rw-r--r--   1 user      user             2 May 14 09:24 ./Main/_Ein\342\201\204Slash/Zw\342\201\204ei\342\201\204Slash

Comment: `\342\201\204` would be a Unicode fraction slash - in a UTF-8 locale that would be an ordinary character not a directory separator and there should be no issues replacing it ex. `rename -n 's/\342\201\204/_/g' *`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the `ls` output in your [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338188/remove-and-replace-all-slashes-from-filenames-recursively#comment2284835_1338188), the character in question is a [Unicode fraction slash](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2044/index.htm) rather than an ordinary ASCII slash (which would be illegal in a Unix filename, since it is used as the path separator character).

In a UTF-8 locale, `⁄` (U+2044, octal `\342\201\204` or hex `0xE2 0x81 0x84`) is an ordinary character that you can manipulate / replace in the usual way with the perl-based `rename` command for example. Ex.:

```
$ touch hello⁄there.txt File⁄name.jpg

$ rename -n 's/\342\201\204/_/g' *
rename(File⁄name.jpg, File_name.jpg)
rename(hello⁄there.txt, hello_there.txt)
```

or

```
$ rename -n 's/\xe2\x81\x84/_/g' *
rename(File⁄name.jpg, File_name.jpg)
rename(hello⁄there.txt, hello_there.txt)
```

Remove the `-n` once you are happy that it is doing the right thing.

If you want to use `find` to descend directories recursively you can do so like

```
find . -type f -name "$(printf '*\342\201\204*')" -execdir rename -n 's/\342\201\204/_/g' {} +
```

(If the *directory* names can contain `\342\201\204` and you want to replace those as well, then you will need to add `-depth` and remove the `-type f` restriction).

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked out so far. I would've never came to that solution myself, thank you for that in-depth explanation aswell.

Comment: Using 
find . -depth -name "$(printf '*\342\201\204*')" -execdir rename 's/\342\201\204/_/g' {} +
I renamed the folders aswell.